# Can't display x-axis value in Highcharts title

Tags: javascript, highcharts

here is example how I need it to work [highchart example](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/tooltip/pointformat/)

if you hover on spot you will see something like

```
Apr
Dog: 2323
```

So it display xAxis value in the tooltip. 
I have made my own but it display chart name instead of xAxis value.

[my highchart](http://jsfiddle.net/3frcqbkv/)

```
xAxis: {
    title: {
        text: 'Date'
    },
    categories: data.categories
},
```

What do I do wrong?

Comment: I don't get it. The date is displayed on your x-axe, what do you want instead?

Comment: @esc I want it display in tooltip when you hover on spot

Comment: The numbers of the days are displayed inside the little tool bar. Do you want some kind of other format?

Comment: @esc I have a date like `05/06`. I want it display on tooltip, like on http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/tooltip/pointformat/ displayed Apr, May...

Comment: I think that you would have to define the pointStart and pointInterval and use your 'data' along with it...

Answer (score 0):

replace what you have in your tooltip formatter- it should work

```
              tooltip: {

                formatter: function () {
                    return  '<b>'+this.series.name+'<br>'+this.x + ':' + this.point.y;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's strange, but in `pointFormat`, `{point.x}` refers to the category **index**, not category **name**. In that case, use `headerFormat` to add that info: http://jsfiddle.net/3frcqbkv/1/

```
        tooltip: {
            headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b><br>{point.x}',
            pointFormat: ': $ {point.y:.2f}'
        },
```

In case you have more series, and you can not use above solution, then use `tooltip.formatter` instead.

**Edit:**

You can get category name this way: `{point.category}`. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3frcqbkv/3/

```
            pointFormat: '{point.category}: $ {point.y:.2f}'
```